# JavaScript. 2 ошибки Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

Новичок в JavaScript. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Выдает две ошибки(не я их тестировал, я просто написал код):

1. selectPage(sdfsdf, sdf, dfg)

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sdfsdf is not defined at :1:12

2. selectPage(0, 0, 0)

> Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined

Кроме как сделать проверку параметров на ноль, я не знаю, что делать.

```
function selectPage(total, pageSize, selected) {    
    // Количество всех страниц  
    var pageCount = Math.ceil(total / (pageSize * 1.0));

    var result = [];

    // Если возможно создается массив на 10 страниц. Т.к. это максимальное количество страниц в гугле
    // Количество страниц от выбранной страницы:
    // Слева = 5
    // Справа = 4
    if (pageCount > 10) {

        // Если selected меньше 7 - просто заполнятся массив от 1 до 10
        if (selected < 7) {
            result = createArray(1, 10);
        }
        // Если справа от selected есть больше, чем 3 страницы
        else if (pageCount - selected > 3) {
            result = createArray(selected - 5, 10);
        }
        // Иначе заполняется массив "с конца"
        else {
            result = createArray(pageCount - 9, 10);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Иначе просто заполнятся массив на количество страниц
        result = createArray(1, pageCount);
    }

    return result;
}

function createArray(startValue, size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result[i] = startValue;
        startValue++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1. Этого вообще в приведённом коде нет. 2. Переменная result не определена. 3. https://ithappens.me/story/1778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Первая ошибка**

Передаваемые аргументы (*sdfsdf, sdf, dfg*) воспринимаются интерпретатором, как переменные. Очевидно, что такие переменные у вас нигде не определены. Если же вы хотите передать текст, то нужно оборачивать в кавычки - (*"sdfsdf", "sdf", "dfg"*).

В данном конкретном случае ваша функция *selectPage*() ожидает передачу чисел.

**Вторая ошибка**

В области видимости функции *createArray*() нет переменной *result*. Она определена только в функции *selectPage*. Для того, чтобы ошибки не было, во вторую функцию, - *createArray*(), - необходимо передавать переменную *result*.

Обе ошибки связаны с отсутствием необходимых переменных. Поэтому и сообщения об ошибках - *Reference errors*.

Ниже приводится исправленная версия Вашего кода.

```js
function selectPage(total, pageSize, selected) {    
    // Количество всех страниц`  
    var pageCount = Math.ceil(total / (pageSize * 1.0));

    var result = [];

    // Если возможно создается массив на 10 страниц. Т.к. это максимальное количество страниц в гугле
    // Количество страниц от выбранной страницы:
    // Слева = 5
    // Справа = 4
    if (pageCount > 10) {

        // Если selected меньше 7 - просто заполнятся массив от 1 до 10
        if (selected < 7) {
            result = createArray(1, 10, result);
        }
        // Если справа от selected есть больше, чем 3 страницы
        else if (pageCount - selected > 3) {
            result = createArray(selected - 5, 10, result);
        }
        // Иначе заполняется массив "с конца"
        else {
            result = createArray(pageCount - 9, 10, result);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Иначе просто заполнятся массив на количество страниц
        result = createArray(1, pageCount, result);
    }

    return result;
}

function createArray(startValue, size, result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result[i] = startValue;
        startValue++;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(selectPage(10, 0, 0));
```